# WordPress & Twitter Bootstrap image issues with stretching or max-width: 100% not working

Tags: css, wordpress, image, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

Using Twitter Bootstrap v3.1.1 I created a custom WordPress theme for a client. All was going well until I realized in IE and Firefox the images were showing full size and outside of the boundaries of their parent elements even though I have `max-width: 100%` set.

I did some hunting around on the internet for options, naturally, and it was mentioned to put `height:auto;` on the img tag. This nearly worked, but images began to be stretched in some places, and still not obeying max-width in others.

Here is an example of images in widgets in the sidebar not obeying `max-width: 100%`

[image: sidebar images not obeying max-width: 100%]

I hunted around some more and came across more hacks for Firefox and IE. Then Chrome started to misbehave as well. Now I have a messy stylesheet with tons of CSS hacks and there are still issues with images being stretched or showing full size. One of the suggestions was to mess with `box-sizing` and set the width of `img` to 100%, which results in the below with smaller images than the width of the parent container being stretched.

[image: stretched images]

I'm about to go back to the drawing board where I'm only using `max-width: 100%` and start over.

My question is: how can I get ALL images used on WordPress to behave correctly and follow the `max-width: 100%` CSS rule? This is a responsive website and I need all images to stay within their containers, NOT be stretched or skewed, and grow/shrink while constraining proportions as the browser size changes.

Comment: @howdy-mcgee Perhaps. I've been developing pages with Twitter Bootstrap for a while now and have only come across this issue on WordPress though. I assumed it was a WordPress-specific issue.

Comment: can you post all the css you have that is effecting the image?

Comment: @pathfinder That would make this an endless, messy post. I'm tempted to just rip out Twitter bootstrap and never use it for a WordPress theme since it's causing so many issues. Boostrap is fine for HTML sites but something about WordPress is causing issues.

Comment: If you use firebug you can see just the "final" css after it cascades and paste that in. I'm sure I could help you get your css right if I saw the css. -- however I feel ya about bootstrap, I don't like it at all. They should call it bloatstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this ended up not being specific to Bootstrap or WordPress. It was a combination of

1. A style I had copied in from who knows where `a { display: inline-block; }`
2. Bootstrap box-sizing on all elements
3. WordPress using `width` and `height` attributes on images

After I took out the weird `a { display: inline-block; }` (that I still don't even know how got there and can only assume I was tired and loopy), most of the image issues went away. I just had to target a few instances of images to get them to behave.

I'm happy to know I can use Boostrap in the future to help speed along project styling. Thanks, everyone, for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of Bootstrap and WordPress together - we use it all the time. You can use

```
img {height: auto; max-width: 100%;}
```

and that will make all of your images responsive, which will also fill their containers **up to 100% of the original image width** and resize the height to maintain the aspect ratio.

If your image's container is 1000px, however, and your image is originally 500x250, the image will only fill up half the container because max-width: 100% will give the image a max-width of 500px.

You can use

```
img {height: auto; width: 100%;}
```

and that will ensure that your image fills the entire container. But beware - in the above 1000px container / 500px image scenario, your image will scale up and might begin to look pixellated.

Another thing to note - your images might be overriden in the widgets. For example, one popular sidebar images widget hardcodes the width and height into an inline style (a horrendous practice and I hope they stop it). You can override that and make it work with:

```
img[style] {height: auto !important; width: 100% !important;} //or
.widget[style] img {height: auto !important; width: 100% !important;}
```

I'm willing to bet that your sidebar image problem is that there are styles (via the plugin css or inline) that are overriding your original image settings.

Comment: Thanks. Those are some of the issues I tried already. It ended up being another issue completely.